# How to loop through List of objects of and compare value in every object in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, for-loop, compare

So I have an **`object`** that stores `Country`, `Year` and `Value`

I then have `List<Object>` which will store objects for each year

**Each `List<object>` consist of data of each range of years**

I'd like to loop through any number of countries, let's say 4, and then in each object I want to retrieve the `value` of each `year`.

### For example

Let's assume we want our object to return data from year `1980` to `1983`

So my code looks like this:

```java
//Example of our data
[AF, 19199437988.8023, 1980, AF, 20050189881.6659, 1981, AF, 20046334303.9661, 1982, AF, 20536542736.7297, 1983]
[UA, 90615023323.7353, 1980, UA, 131805126738.287, 1981, UA, 181334417615.413, 1982, UA, 175781379051.433, 1983]
[ID, 861933968740.332, 1980, ID, 890487074595.966, 1981, ID, 912524136718.019, 1982, ID, 917869913364.916, 1983]
[AU, 1339539063150.01, 1980, AU, 1454675479665.84, 1981, AU, 1563950959269.52, 1982, AU, 1537477830480.51, 1983]

// each value is a country. 'AF' stands for AFghanistan, and so on...
String[] countries = new String[] {
  "AF", "UA", "ID", "AU"
};

for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; ++i) {
  if (countries.get(i).getYear() == "I don't know how to retrieve each year here.") {
    System.out.println(countries.get(i));
  }
}
```

Is this possible? If so then how can I get it?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have such structure? why don't you build a POJO with those attributes?

Comment: This is just to illustrate my problem. I don't have such structure in my real application.

The data above the code is just an example of how my data looks like @FedericoJoséSorenson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you had declared your POJO:

```
public class MyObject {
    Integer year;
    String country;
    BigDecimal value;
    public MyObject(Integer year, String country, BigDecimal value) {
        super();
        this.year = year;
        this.country = country;
        this.value = value;
    }
    //getter/setter
}
```

And after you had created and added object values in the list:

```
...
MyObject af1 = new MyObject(1980,"AF",new BigDecimal("19199437988.8023"));
MyObject af2 = new MyObject(1981,"AF",new BigDecimal("20050189881.6659"));
MyObject af3 = new MyObject(1982,"AF",new BigDecimal("20046334303.9661"));
MyObject af4 = new MyObject(1983,"AF",new BigDecimal("20536542736.7297"));
...
MyObject ua1 = new MyObject(1980,"UA",new BigDecimal("90615023323.7353"));
MyObject ua2 = new MyObject(1981,"UA",new BigDecimal("131805126738.287"));
MyObject ua3 = new MyObject(1982,"UA",new BigDecimal("181334417615.413"));
MyObject ua4 = new MyObject(1983,"UA",new BigDecimal("175781379051.433"));
...

List<MyObject> completeList = Arrays.asList(af1,af2,af3,af4,ua1,ua2,ua3,ua4,id1,id2,id3,id4,au1,au2,au3,au4);
```

You could use java8 streams in order to get what you're looking for:

1) Filter the original list in order to get only object with `1980<=year<=1983`:

```
int yearFrom =1980;
int yearTo =1983;   
List<MyObject> filteredList = completeList.stream().filter(s -> s.getYear()>=yearFrom && s.getYear()<=yearTo).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

2) Get a `map(year,value)` for each country i.e. for `AF`:

```
Map<Integer, BigDecimal> map = filteredList.stream()
        .filter(s -> ("AF").equals(s.getCountry()))
          .collect(
              Collectors.toMap(
                 s -> ((MyObject)s).getYear(),
                 s -> ((MyObject)s).getValue())
         );
System.out.println("(year,value) for AF Country are:");
System.out.println(map);
```

You could get a map like this: `Map(country,Map(year,value))`, in the following way:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, BigDecimal>> mapCountries = filteredList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getCountry,
        Collectors.toMap( 
                s -> s.getYear(),
                s -> s.getValue()))
        );
```

Then you can iterate through the countries and do `mapCountries.get(country)` in order to obtain the `Map(year,value)` for each country.

Comment: How comes when printed, they are on the wrong order? So the first year startes from 1984, and 1980 is printed at the end. If I give years from 1980 to 2015

Comment: You could navigate and print map entries in the ascending order (from 1980 to 1984): `map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, BigDecimal>comparingByKey()).forEach(System.out::println);` or descending (from 1984-1980) `map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, BigDecimal>comparingByKey().reversed()).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: Thank you. Just one more thing, how can I use the map to go through each country, rather than "AF" ?

Comment: Look at the answer for this last request ;)

Comment: Haha! Apologies, just read the whole thing. :) Thanks bud. Great Champ!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer:
"This is just to illustrate my problem. I don't have such structure in my real application. The data above the code is just an example of how my data looks like"

I would suggest you to create a POJO that stores that data:

```
class POJO { //add nice name to class!
    private Map<Integer, Double> yearValueMap;
    private String countryName;
    // add setter and getter here.
    add(Integer year, Double value) {
        this.yearValueMap.put(year, value);
    }
}
```

And then you create objects that are storing that data, something like:

```
POJO pojo = new POJO();
pojo.add(1890, 14.31);
pojo.setCountryName("Italy");
```

and so you have objects containing this data. Then you have a

```
List<POJO> countryInformation;
```

that you can iterate.

Hope it helps and that I did not make any typo, I've coded it here.

Editing for adding the code in the comment:

```
List <Object> myData = receiveDataFromApi();
for(int i = 0; i < myData.size(); i+=3) {
    ...
    pojo.setCountryName= myData.get(i);
    pojo.add(myData.get(i+2), myData.get(i+1));
    ...
}
```

I've used the POJO just for making the point, but you should use your own model for that.

Comment: However this data that you are seeing is actually received from an API. Ive already created a class for the object that will store country, year and value.

Comment: Then directly map it, no? I mean, you will have something like:

List <Object> myData = receiveDataFromApi();
for(int i = 0; i< myData.size(); i+=3) {
    pojo.setCountryName= myData.get(i);
    pojo.add(myData.get(i+2), myData.get(i+1));
}

(I've used the same pojo I've build before to make it easier to follow. I'll edit the post with the code too now).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem :D Hope it helps ^^